# Using SignalR as a standalone server application, and not an Asp.Net one

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

As promising as [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) sounds, I don't like the fact that it's an Asp.Net application. To be honest I'm a C# developer who is not familiar with Asp.Net concepts a bit. I've used C# as an application language but never as a webserver language (I don't think I have seen beyond IIS4, the last of it was when I used ASP and VB).

My question is, can I use SignalR as a standalone server application that don't make use of IIS or Asp.Net? How?

Comment: Do you know what SignalR is? Does? and the problem it solves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, you can self-host!

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-signalr-self-host

Hope this helps!

Comment: new link http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host